# How to move to top/bottom of region delimited by consecutive blank lines

Tags: cursor-motions, navigation

I have two commands for somewhat emulating the Emacs command `narrow-to-defun`.

I have two commands that move to the top/bottom of the current paragraph

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gt mp{zfgg`p

nnoremap <silent> <leader>gb mp}zfG`p
```

And this works really well for languages where people don't tend to leave blank lines in the middle of function bodies or other "interesting" pieces of code.

However, I have some projects where I use >=2 blank lines to separate units of code and liberally use single blank lines inside function bodies.

Is there an easy way to move by "big paragraphs", skipping over singleton blank lines?

For instance a lot of python code looks like, with occasional blank lines within function bodies and two blank lines separating them. Other things that are similar to top-level function definitions, like classes, are spaced accordingly.

```
def some_function(a, b, c):
    # do stuff


def some_other_function(a, c):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gt ?^\n\{2,}<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <leader>gb /^\n\{2,}<CR>
```

Find more with `:help regex`